# How to publish Flutter test results in some common format to display in TFS/VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, flutter, flutter-test

Is there a way to publish Flutter test results e.g. in JUnit or XUnit format to be able to parse and analyze them in VSTS/TFS?

I didn't find any way to export Flutter test results in any "organized" way e.g. json or xml file.

Answer (score 3):

In TFS/VSTS the [Test: Publish Test Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=vsts) task supports popular test result formats including JUnit, NUnit 2, NUnit 3, Visual Studio Test (TRX), and xUnit 2. Flutter test result is not supported.

However there is a application [junitreport](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/junitreport) which can be used to convert the results of dart tests to JUnit xml reports. Seems it's compatible with the Flutter platform, you can have a try for that.